# How to speed up this VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

in this code looking at 2 worksheets that contain similar data from different systems. Column 1 contains a unique staff number so there can be a match on the person then here there is a difference in NiNo `ws1.cell(,17) and ws2.cell(,24)` between the sheets then certain values for that person are copied to a 3rd sheet.

How ever there are to be 18 different worksheets all looking at different criteria, so this code will have to run 18 times and will take a while. any ideas how I can speed it up examples please

```
 Sub NINODifferences()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, iCol As Long, iRow As Long


    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SheetA")
    Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SheetB")
    Set ws3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("NINO Differences")


    iRow = 2
    iCol = 1

        For i = 1 To ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For j = 1 To ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

                If Trim(ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value2) = Trim(ws2.Cells(j, 1).Value2) Then

                    If Trim(ws1.Cells(i, 17).Value2) <> Trim(ws2.Cells(j, 24).Value2) Then

                        ws3.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value2
                        iCol = iCol + 1
                        ws3.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value2
                        iCol = iCol + 1
                        ws3.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value2
                        iCol = iCol + 1
                        ws3.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, 17).Value2
                        iCol = iCol + 1
                        ws3.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value2 = ws2.Cells(j, 24).Value2

                        iCol = 1
                        iRow = iRow + 1


                    Else
                    End If


                Else
                End If

            Next j
       Next i

    Set ws1 = Nothing
    Set ws2 = Nothing
    Set ws3 = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you checked how long it takes?

Comment: to run once takes around 2 minutes but times that by 18 eventually will be a very long time

Comment: `ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` (and for ws2) these values don't change so I would store them in variables.

Comment: It won't necessarily take 18 times as long.

Comment: I would also store range references for things like `ws3.Cells(iRow, iCol)` rather than reevaluating it each time. This applies to a lot of your statements. Then use Offset to navigate relative to these references.

Comment: ws3 is going to be a different sheet everytime round there will be 18 different ws3

Comment: example first time it looks for National insurance number differences, then put that on the National insurance differences sheet(ws3) then. It will look for Date of birth differences and put all them in separate sheet

Comment: Code optimization belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ it is too broad for this forum.

Comment: thanks added it to there.

Comment: Do you have a sample workbook you can share?

Answer (score 4):

Try to rewrite the your code (it will be a tough job), trying to do the following:

- Read the corresponding cells and save them to an array (or multiple arrays for multiple ranges)
- Make all the calculations and conditional evaluations until you receive an array with the results
- Write this array to the worksheet

---

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim firstArr        As Variant
    Dim secondArr       As Variant
    Dim cnt             As Long

    firstArr = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A20"))
    secondArr = Application.Transpose(Range("B1:B20"))

    'Read the corresponding cells and save them to an array
    'Here instead of reading I am generating them
    For cnt = LBound(firstArr) To UBound(firstArr)
        firstArr(cnt) = cnt
        secondArr(cnt) = cnt * 3
        Cells(cnt, 1) = firstArr(cnt)
        Cells(cnt, 2) = secondArr(cnt)
    Next cnt

    'Make all the calculations until you receive an array with the results
    For cnt = LBound(firstArr) To UBound(secondArr)
        firstArr(cnt) = firstArr(cnt) + secondArr(cnt)
    Next cnt

    'Write this array to the worksheet
    For cnt = LBound(firstArr) To UBound(secondArr)
        Cells(cnt, 3) = firstArr(cnt)
    Next cnt

End Sub
```

The performance bonus would be noticeable if you manage to do it.
And as a small (unwanted) advice - do not use this line, some people consider it a bad habit:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Comment: please explain better your code and how it does what im trying to do Sheet A and Sheet B are deleted and recreated everytime it is opened so will never be the same sheet number

Comment: @Leighholling - it does not do what you are trying to do. It just gives an example how to save ranges to array and do the calculations there.

Comment: I don't think setting to manual calculation is a bad habit, as long as we switch it back to its original state after our processing.

Comment: @AndyG - here we think differently. But everyone has his own opinion.

Comment: sl1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row this has shaved about 30% of time off by putting this in a variant

Comment: @Leighholling - and if you put it in a `Long` it would save about 31% :)

Comment: I tend to agree that setting calculation to manual and screen updating false to be somewhat discouraged.. if the code execution is halted without proper error handling the settings end up stuck.. and in this example they're not reset, also there are times when the user may have turned them off and here we're not capturing the beginning state either

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of what Vityata is talking about (rewrite your code to use arrays) and not completely sure what your data looks like you could use something like this:

```
 Sub NINODifferences()

Dim ws1 As Variant, ws2 As Variant, ws3 As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long

ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SheetA").UsedRange
ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SheetB").UsedRange
ReDim ws3(4, 0)
    For i = 1 To UBound(ws1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(ws2)
            If Trim(ws1(i, 1)) = Trim(ws2(j, 1)) Then
                If Trim(ws1(i, 17)) <> Trim(ws2(j, 24)) Then
                    ReDim Preserve ws3(4, count)
                    ws3(0, count) = ws1(i, 1)
                    ws3(1, count) = ws1(i, 2)
                    ws3(2, count) = ws1(i, 3)
                    ws3(3, count) = ws1(i, 17)
                    ws3(4, count) = ws2(i, 24)
                    count = count + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next j
   Next i
Call PasteArray(transposeArray(ws3), ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("NINO Differences").[A1])
Set ws1 = Nothing
Set ws2 = Nothing

End Sub

Sub PasteArray(data As Variant, rng As Range)
    rng.Resize(UBound(data, 1) + 1, UBound(data, 2) + 1) = data
End Sub

Function transposeArray(data)
If IsEmpty(data) Then Exit Function
ReDim r(UBound(data, 2), UBound(data))
For i = LBound(r) To UBound(r)
    For j = LBound(r, 2) To UBound(r, 2)
        r(i, j) = data(j, i)
    Next j
Next i
transposeArray = r
End Function
```

Comment: this is fab but how do I make it put the results into new sheet at the second row, its a template so will be headers

Comment: done it thanks, now another question for you how can I re use this code to look for different things in different areas so lets say compare column 9 in both sheets and put it in a different sheet

Comment: on Call PasteArray(...) change [A1] to [A2]

Comment: you're fast! on your if statements - the column numbers should remain the same note If Trim(ws1(i, 1)) = Trim(ws2(j, 1)) and If Trim(ws1(i, 17)) <> Trim(ws2(j, 24))   you can set the column numbers within the arrays for ws1 / ws2 the same way you'd reference the cells in your worksheets

Comment: although for this setup you'd need to include additional arrays for each of the additional sheets you'd like to paste the comparison data into.. and after building the entire array you'd paste it using the call PasteArray(datatopaste, range to paste into)

Comment: I have figured it out you sir are a genius running time is a few second I have just changed the (I,17) and (I, 24) edited this line and it pastes the data into a separate sheet    Call PasteArray(transposeArray(ws3), ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DoB Differences").[A2])

Comment: Excellent! glad to help :)